# creating lambda function with eventbridge event as a trigger with cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a lambda function with an eventbridge event as a trigger using cdk in python. This is what I want to build. See screenshot.

This is what I have tried:

```
my_lambda_function = _lambda.Function(
    self,
    'LambdaFunction',
    code=_lambda.Code.from_inline(function_config['code']),
    handler=function_config['handler'],
    runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
    role=role,
    function_name='lambda-function-liberty-stack'
)

print("Deploy Lambda Function")

with open(template_dir+lambda_file_name, 'r') as f:
    function_config = yaml.safe_load(f)
       
my_lambda_function = _lambda.Function(
    self,
    'LambdaFunction',
    code=_lambda.Code.from_inline(function_config['code']),
    handler=function_config['handler'],
    runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
    role=role,
    function_name='lambda-function-liberty-stack'
)

# Define Event Bridge Rule
lambda_rule = events.Rule(self, "Create_Pipeline_Rule",
    description="Rule to run lambda function which builds code pipeline. This monitors code repos in project.",
    rule_name="event-rule-code-pipeline-lambda",
    event_pattern= events.EventPattern(
      source= ["aws.codecommit"],
      detail_type= ["CodeCommit Repository State Change"],
      detail= {
          "event": ["referenceDeleted", "referenceCreated"],
          "referenceType": ["branch"],
      }
    )
)
    
lambda_rule.add_target(_lambda.Function.from_function_arn(
    self,
    id= 'lambda-function-liberty-stack',
    function_arn= my_lambda_function.function_arn
))
```

I am getting the following error:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aws_cdk/aws_events/**init**.py", line 9865, in add_target
return typing.cast(None, jsii.invoke(self, "addTarget", [target]))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/**init**.py", line 149, in wrapped
return _recursize_dereference(kernel, fn(kernel, *args, **kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/**init**.py", line 399, in invoke
response = self.provider.invoke(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 377, in invoke
return self._process.send(request, InvokeResponse)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 339, in send
raise RuntimeError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
RuntimeError: TypeError: target.bind is not a function

Comment: Don't post screenshots, post text instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue

```
    print("Deploy Lambda Function")

    # Define lambda function
    my_lambda_function = _lambda.Function(
        self,
        'LambdaFunction',
        code=_lambda.Code.from_inline(function_config['code']),
        handler=function_config['handler'],
        runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
        role=role,
        function_name='lambda-function-123'
    )
    
    # Define Event Bridge Rule
    lambda_rule = events.CfnRule(self, "Create_Pipeline_Rule",
        description="Rule to run lambda function which builds code pipeline",
        name="event-rule-code-pipeline-lambda",
        event_pattern= {
          "source": ["aws.codecommit"],
          "detail-type": ["CodeCommit Repository State Change"],
           "detail": {
                "event": ["referenceDeleted", "referenceCreated"],
                "referenceType": ["branch"],
            }
        },
        targets=[events.CfnRule.TargetProperty(
            arn=my_lambda_function.function_arn,
            id='lambda-function-123'
        )]
    )
    
    # Add permissions
    my_lambda_function.add_permission(
        "Permission_Invoke_Lambda",
        principal=iam.ServicePrincipal('events.amazonaws.com'),
        action="lambda:*",
        source_arn=lambda_rule.attr_arn
    )
```